# UITabbar disappearing even with navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have embedded a `viewController` in a `NavigationController` and set it as the `rootViewController`. Then I connected the `TabBarController` to the `NavigationController`. I have a button in the `LessonViewController` that shows the `PurchaseViewController`, and then a back button in the `PurchaseViewController` which shows the `LessonViewController`. However, the tab bar was still present in the `PurchaseViewController` so I ticked `hideBottomBarOnPush`, which solved this problem, however, when I segued back to the `LessonViewController` the tab bar had disappeared.

Any ideas?

The following image is what my storyboard looks like now:

[image: image link]

Comment: You shouldn't push another LessonViewController when pressing the back button, but you should pop the PurchaseViewController. If you push another LessonViewController the old PurchaseViewController will still be in the navigation stack.

Comment: I have taken your advice and popped he viewcontroller! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Similar to barb’s code, I got this to work, while enabling “hide bottom toolbar when pushed” and then popping the view controller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = false
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should do following way,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Your_Identifier" {
        hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false }
    }
}
```

It will show TabBar reappears while segue back.

Comment: I haven’t tested this, as one of the previous answers has solved it and I have decided to pop the view controller, but I may use that for other situations so thanks!

Comment: @HarryStuart I have tested it and it is absolutely working

Comment: I shall use it when I am segueing between views in the future!